# How to stream movies from LG Network Storage N2B1D to iPad (DLNA Player)?

Tags: video, ipad, streaming

I'm looking for a DLNA Player on iPad...

I'm the owner of a brand new *LG Network Storage N2B1D*.

I want to stream movies (or images) through a local network.
For now, I can browse files with a Mac or iPhone/iPad but I can't read content.

How to do this?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dlna service needs to be enabled on your Nas then you can use a media player such as Oplayer which has a free version in the app store. There are quite a few free media players apps that should be able to browse the Nas.

Comment: Oh, nice. I'll try it asap. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a DLNA player for iPad.  However, if you have a computer in your home that can run iTunes, then add the content that is sitting on the NAS to iTunes (use option+drag so it doesn't copy the file) and then ensure the iPad and iTunes are both using the same account.  This will allow the iPad to stream our content using Apple's Home Sharing.

Comment: Ok, another way to do it, cool.

Comment: On my Nas I've a lot of avi files, so this is not working everytime.